# Azure Pipelines - A way for the file recognition pattern to work with (Visual Studio) Solution Folders?

Tags: azure-devops, pattern-matching, azure-pipelines

### Context:

I have a few projects in the same solution which I push through a pipeline that packs them into NuGet packages and stores them in my Azure Artifacts storage.

The steps are:

> 1. Install NuGet
> 2. NuGet restore
> 3. Build solution
> 4. Run tests
> 5. NuGet pack (dotnet pack, to be specific, as they are .NET Standard targeting)
> 6. NuGet push (to Artifacts storage)

However, the solution contains a few yet unfinished package projects that I don't want to pack yet as well as my test project, which should also be excluded.

Simple enough, in that case my file matching pattern would just include the names of the projects I want, like:

```
'**/*Proj1.csproj;**/*Proj2.csproj;**/*Proj3.csproj;'
```

But now I want a few new projects to be added to this shipping 'set'. Therefore my pattern will have to include them as well.

```
'**/*Proj1.csproj;**/*Proj2.csproj;**/*Proj3.csproj;**/*Proj4.csproj;**/*Proj5.csproj;'
```

As you can see, that's hardly generic. I have to modify the pattern every time something changes, gets included, or if I reverse it - every time I want to exclude a project.

I'm looking to apply the same pipeline, or at least the structure (as much as I can), to a few solutions of the same type, which I'd like to make possible with a few naming conventions I have in place.

### Question:

Is there a way to turn:

```
'**/*Proj1.csproj;**/*Proj2.csproj;**/*Proj3.csproj;**/*Proj4.csproj;**/*Proj5.csproj;'
```

into

```
'**/Packages/**.csproj;' //or something very similar
```

Where 'Packages' is a VS Solution folder (because actual folders don't work inside the base of a solution), with the end goal being every project inside the 'Packages' solution folder being discovered (and packed), and ignoring everything outside of it.

*The problem being that solution folders are not an actual part of the path structure...*

**PS -** 
Workarounds I have considered -

- Have a keyword in the names of all projects I want to ignore like "Foo.Ignore.csproj" and then exclude all that contain "Ignore" in the name.
- Unloading/removing the unfinished projects from the solution but **a)** I want to make sure they are held in buildable and testable state and **b)** since they remain in the repository path, they are still discoverable by the matching pattern.

However I don't feel like this is such a far fetched use-case that it wouldn't have a "supported" solution (I could be wrong, of course). Or there is a different 'best practice' established?

Comment: What's wrong with '**/Packages/**.csproj;'?

Comment: @grmbl Ideally, I wouldn't have to go through the manual process of removing a project, moving it around in filespace and adding it again every time I want to add/remove a project from that Packages folder.